# Adding Libgdx as project dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

Recently I decided to start a new project using Libgdx. However there are some things that I need to behave slightly different from what is in the library, so I decided to clone the library, do my changes and use the local modified version as a library in my project. Bellow is my folder hierarchy:

```
Project
    |--files
libgdx
    |--files
```

According to [this](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/) link, all I have to do is to add

```
include ':libgdx'
project(':libgdx').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../libgdx')
```

to my `settings.gradle` file, and

```
compile project(":libgdx")
```

to my `build.gradle`. However when I try to build, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Another attempt was to import just the core libgdx module (the one called `gdx`) to my project using the Android Studio module settings, but even before adding anything to `build.gradle`, I immediately get the following error message:

```
Error:Could not get unknown property 'libraries' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I've done the steps pointed [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Running-demos-%26-tests) to clone and build the source code. Does anyone know all the steps required to use libgdx as dependency locally?

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX uses a Gradle based setup application which will download all that's required automatically!

go to this page https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html

click to "download setup app"
this is a light app for create empty project.